# Add an app to the Google Playstore installed list

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have recently have had to flash my GApps package on Cyanogen. As a result all the application that were previously listed in the installed apps section are no longer present any more.

Is there any way I can add them back there so that PlayStore will continue to track updates for them ?

Comment: Are the apps themselves still installed on your phone?

Comment: @Arielle Yup. All there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)'s **Market**<sup>[sic]</sup> **Doctor** feature to restore your apps to the 'Installed' list in Google Play Store. Here's how:

- Open Titanium Backup.
- Press the **Menu** button on your device.
- Select **Market**<sup>[sic]</sup> **Doctor** .
- From the popup, select **User apps** or **User and system apps** depending on which kind of app isn't showing up on your 'Installed' list.
- **Select all** apps from the list that will show up, or choose just the ones you want to show up in Google Play Store, then select **Done** in the upper-right corner of the screen.
- Wait until the operation finishes.
- Open **Google Play Store**'s Installed list and your apps should be there.

Cheers.