# Play store does not list any installed apps

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-play-store

After installing CM11 and corresponding gapps I no longer see any installed apps listed in the Play Store. Is there any way to have them relisted without re-installing all the apps? I have tried clearing the Play Store data and cache.

Comment: Similar question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115547/add-an-app-to-the-google-playstore-installed-list

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not seem to be limited to Cyanogenmod devices. I experienced it on most new devices: Pre-installed apps are not recognized by Google Playstore.

The only way I found to make Google Playstore recognize that an app is installed is to search for the app in the Playstore. Usually the Playstore has an update for the pre-installed app and if you install this update manually the app will afterwards be listed as installed app in Google Playstore.